# Change quantity in Stripe Client Only Code Snippet

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe's Client Only method of selling a product from a website. A snippet of javascript code is copied from the Prices section of a Product created in a Stripe account and pasted into an html page. This creates a Checkout Button which takes you to a Stripe hosted checkout page for that Product.

I want the user to be able to choose how many units of the product they buy and I noticed in the code snippet there is a property called `quantity` which has a value of 1. I can replace that value with a variable (I called `numb`) and, if I assign a number to the variable earlier in the page, then when I checkout that number of items is displayed and the price is changed accordingly. This is what I want. The problem is that every attempt I make to write code so the user can input the number of the product they want so that the quantity variable is updated and fed into the code snippet results in the button failing to work (ie. fails to load Stripe's checkout page).

Is it supposed to be possible to do this? If so how can it be done?

I have pasted the html page below with my javascript additions indicated. If I comment out the `var numb = 2;` line the Checkout button fails to load the checkout page. I was hoping the earlier assignment to ```numb`` would work. That is:

```
var numb = document.getElementById('number-tickets').value;
```

In this case the user would enter the number of units they want into an input box and then click a button which would run a function which puts the value of the input box into `numb`. This and various other ideas I tried all result in the Checkout button failing to load the Checkout page when clicked. The only thing that works is when I directly assign an integer to `numb`.

The full code for the page is reproduced below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML Template</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Load Stripe.js on your website. -->
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>

  <P>How many tickets do you want to buy?</p>
  <input type="number" id="number-tickets">
  <button id="testing">How many?</button>

  <script>
  // ***MY CODE***
    var howManyButton = document.getElementById('testing');
    howManyButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      var numb = document.getElementById('number-tickets').value;
    });
  // ***END OF MY CODE***
  </script>

  <!-- Create a button that your customers click to complete their purchase. Customize the styling to suit your branding. -->
  <button
    style="background-color:#6772E5;color:#FFF;padding:8px 12px;border:0;border-radius:4px;font-size:1em"
    id="checkout-button-price_1H2N4aGmidqBA55lmQkZyjQy"
    role="link"
    type="button"
  >
    Checkout
  </button>

  <div id="error-message"></div>

  <script>
    // ***MY CODE***
    var numb = 2;
    // ***END OF MY CODE***
  </script>

  <script>
  (function() {
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_...redacted...');

    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-price_1H2N4aGmidqBA55lmQkZyjQy');
    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
      // them to Checkout.
       stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        // ***MY CODE*** I replace the integer, 1, with my variable, numb
        lineItems: [{price: 'price_1H2N4aGmidqBA55lmQkZyjQy', quantity: numb}],
        // ***END OF MY CODE***
        mode: 'payment',
        // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
        // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
        // a successful payment.
        // Instead use one of the strategies described in
        // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
        successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//stevespages.org.uk/success',
        cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//stevespages.org.uk/canceled',
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
          // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
          var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
          displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
        }
      });
    });
  })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Edit:***

I took off the `var` prefix from `numb` in response to **cjav_dev**'s answer but if the user enters a number and clicks the **How Many?** button and then clicks **Checkout** the checkout page still fails to load. If they do not click the **How Many?** button then the checkout page loads but of course it just has the number of units hardcoded with the `var numb = 7;` statement. I have now made a couple of other alterations to the code which I think might help to identify the problem and pasted it below.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML Template</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Load Stripe.js on your website. -->
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>

  <P>How many tickets do you want to buy?</p>
  <input type="number" id="number-tickets">
  <button id="testing">How many?</button>

  <p id="test-for-numb"></p>

  <script>
    // ***MY CODE***
    var numb = 7;
    // User Chooses
    var howManyButton = document.getElementById('testing');
    howManyButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      numb = document.getElementById('number-tickets').value;
      // document.getElementById('test-for-numb').innerHTML = numb;
    });
    // ***END OF MY CODE***
  </script>

  <!-- Create a button that your customers click to complete their purchase. Customize the styling to suit your branding. -->
  <button
    style="background-color:#6772E5;color:#FFF;padding:8px 12px;border:0;border-radius:4px;font-size:1em"
    id="checkout-button-price_1H2N4aGmidqBA55lmQkZyjQy"
    role="link"
    type="button"
  >
    Checkout
  </button>

  <div id="error-message"></div>
  
  <script>
  (function() {
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_...redacted...');

    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-price_1H2N4aGmidqBA55lmQkZyjQy');
    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
      // them to Checkout.
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        // ***MY CODE*** I replace the integer, 1, with my variable, numb
        lineItems: [{price: 'price_1H2N4aGmidqBA55lmQkZyjQy', quantity: numb}],
        // ***END OF MY CODE***
        mode: 'payment',
        // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
        // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
        // a successful payment.
        // Instead use one of the strategies described in
        // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
        successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//stevespages.org.uk/success',
        cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//stevespages.org.uk/canceled',
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
          // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
          var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
          displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
        }
      });
    });
  })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty close! The issue is that the variable `numb` is being created inside of the function scope of the callback to the click handler for your `howManyButton` rather than setting a variable in a parent scope. This happens because of the `var` keyword infront of `numb` inside of the function.

Try this:

```
  <script>
  // ***MY CODE***
    var howManyButton = document.getElementById('testing');
    howManyButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      numb = document.getElementById('number-tickets').value;
    });
  // ***END OF MY CODE***
  </script>
```

Note the lack of `var` inside of the click handler. Rather than creating a new variable inside of that function scope, it'll update the existing `numb` variable that is currently set on the window.

Comment: Thanks. I did that but it is still not working. I have added an edit to the end of my question including a new version of the code which I think is more logically displayed but is essentially the same as the first version but without the ```var```  keyword inside the function as you suggested.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to make sure it's possible before going this route.